# Using COUNTIFS with 2 criteria on 2 different sized ranges?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

For my current research I want to return a count of a value (A, B or C) listed in column AO, when a criteria in a differently sized range (T:Y) is met. The criteria is that it simply has to be a specific word (lets say "Jack", "Tony" and "Bobby")

Example:

[image]

I would for instance like to know all the A, B & C's for all the Jacks (in this case 2, 0, 1) but i can't seem to use the countifs formula as it requires the ranges of both criteria to be the same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That would be a SumProduct formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(A2:C5="Jack")*--(D2:D5="A"))
```